# Adding bootsrap dropdown style in rails 4 app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the code that i'm using to render a drop down list in a form.

```
<label class= 'sniglet'> Nationality</label>
<%= f.select(:nationality_id, @nationalities.map {|n| [n.country_name, n.id]}, :class => 'form-control') %>
```

The default bootstrap style doesn't seem to be working. What could be the problem?

Comment: can you get the select tag to show up at least without any design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per rails api, syntax for select form helper is

```
select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

You are passing `class: 'form-control'` as third parameter, that's why it is not applying that class, you can check it using developer tools in browser. Pass it as fourth parameter.

e.g.

```
<%= f.select(:nationality_id, @nationalities.map {|n| [n.country_name, n.id]}, {}, class: 'form-control') %>
```